# Should `docker-compose.yml` be in its own repository?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm building a small web app with Vue.js and an Express API, each with their own `Dockerfile`. I currently am able to build those images and publish them to a private Docker repository, then pull them onto a virtual machine and run them. I want to add Docker Compose, and I've often seen that together with the code for the services, such as

```
|--..
|__api/
|__client/
|__docker-compose.yml
```

but that seem then like you can't publish the images to a repository, since Docker Compose builds the images and runs the containers, and so my VM would need to pull all the code, when to my thinking it should just need the images and then know how to run them.

So am I thinking about Docker Compose wrong? I have very little experience with it; I'm just trying to figure out the best way to be able to run the containers and it seems like I should be able to do that on a VM without having to download all the source code to that VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use docker-compose and still publish the individual images.

I guess that the API and the client have their own Docker files respectively.
So basically you have three options:

1. Let docker-compose build the images via the [build
   option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build).
2. Just reference the images with the [image
   option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#image) and
   make sure they are built before.
3. Do both so docker-compose will build those images *and* give them
   the name and the tag that you put under the image option.

They are all valid options as far as I am concerned. If you go with
option two I would write a little Makefile or script that makes sure
the images are in place for convenience.

Comment: If the images are published though, wouldn't you want to make the docker-compose file available in its own repo, because otherwise to run elsewhere you'd need to either run the containers on their own, or rewrite a docker-compose, right?

Comment: If you just reference the docker images and not build them you can totally put them in a different repository.